# Replace comma with with different comma ، in database field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a field in a table where I store multiple tags separated with comma for example

```
tag1, tag2, tag3,tag4
```

I need to replace a single comma with `،` for Persian version
so that tags will look like

```
tag1، tag2، tag3،tag4،
```

I have over three thousand records in the database and tags are stored with either `،` or `,` but I want all of them to be separated with `،`.

How can I find and replace all `,` with `،` using SQL.

I am using SQL Server as my database.

Let us say table structure is

Table BLOG

BLOG Table fields

```
ID int
Title nVarchar(300)
Description nVarchar(500)
Details nVarchar(max)
Date DateTime
Tags nVarchar(300)
Image varchar(60)
CategoryID int
Updated DateTime
Created DateTime
Published Boolean
```

Comment: Read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is **Absolutly yes!**

Comment: In my case the use is simple i don't need primary key or unique values in this field. it is used for simple search functionality of block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `REPLACE()`:

```
Update BLOG
SET Tags = REPLACE(Tags, N',', N'،')
```

Find and replace with Unicode character(s)

Comment: I was looking at Replace, Will it replace all the accurances of `,` in a single field

Comment: @Learning Yes, it should replace all occurrences.

Comment: I tried it on actual data but it didnt work. data example `الرين,مجلس التعاون الجي, العاربي، دبي,  الخل البي, الاتحاد الأوروبي`

Comment: @Learning `Update BLOG SET Tags = REPLACE(Tags, N',', N'،')` ;).